# How to Remove Duplicate Joomla Update Menu Item?

Tags: menu-item

While updating to Joomla 3.6.2, Joomla thoughtfully installed a second but unwanted menu item into the Components menu. Both show the same URL for link. Is there any way to remedy this?

Comment: Which component was this for?

Comment: The menu item is the "Joomla Update" menu item - which should be there, just not twice.

Answer (score 2):

you could always removed it from the database, go to table `xxx_extensions`

and remove the relevant entry

Comment: Same issue here. Looking in the table, there were two entries for the same component. Removing one fixed the issue.